# Is this essay title critical?

Tags: essay, titles

I'm currently writing a critical essay, arguing individualism, narcissism and collectivism within an online society.

However I feel that the title I've come of up with for this essay just isn't critical? Should the title be more engaging and argue a quote, or a specific piece of theory, or is this title critical enough? Please see below:

"A critical examination of individualism, narcissism and collectivism within Facebook"

Many thanks :)

Comment: This is tough to answer. Can you define "critical" for your purposes? Why are you so concerned with the title and not the essay's content?

Comment: It is to provide critical analysis of the chosen online culture. Apparently the title is an indicator of the quality of content. I think I am on the right lines with the content though, so I suppose it's about the first impression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your title is fine as a subtitle or a deck, but it needs something catchier to start with.

> I Me Ours: A critical examination of individualism, narcissism and collectivism within Facebook
>
> E Pluribus Farmville: A critical examination of individualism, narcissism and collectivism within Facebook

and so on. Puns, lyrics, movie titles, proverbs — go nuts.